# Create universal app using iOS StoryBoard that have different UI

Tags: ios, xcode4.3, uistoryboard, ipad

I'm new with iOS and yesterday i learnt about storyboard. it works great. i refer to [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1). I tried to create iPhone apps with a storyboard.

But now i want to create an universal apps, that means for iPhone and iPad. but also using the storyboard. lets say if i have the same UI, that wont be an issue. Same UI means, my iPhone UI using tab bar controller, my iPad also use a tab bar controller. I just need to point to the same class, and the result will be the same. Now, i want have a different UI. my iPhone will use a tab bar, but my iPad will use a split view.

here is my question :

1. is that possible to do that with device target universal? i mean iPhone with tab bar, iPad with split view.
2. if yes, how can i know which device is running? either i choose iPad or iPhone. How can i know i run on iPhone/iPad? what should I validate in the appdelegate?
3. For ipad storyboard, i drag a split view controller but i can't see any master detail whenever i run the apps. how can it be like that?

thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a Universal application (an application that supports both iPhone and iPad), Xcode will by default give you two Storyboards - one for iPhone, one for iPad. Under your target's settings you'll see a place where you can configure which Storyboard presents the main interface - you can set this separately for iPhone and iPad:

[image]

The OS will take care of loading the correct Storyboard for you.

If you want to detect in code whether you're running on an iPhone or iPad, you can use `USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`. For example:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

There's also `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` for iPad.